# PHP 5 and Strict Standards error

Tags: php

Why I get this error?:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method Hello_Misc::fix_protocol() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in test.php on line 834

line 834:

```
$this->my_url = Hello_Misc::fix_protocol($my, 1);
```

I am using latest version of PHP (>= 5.1.3) but in previous version (<= 5.1.2) it does work ([ref](http://3v4l.org/ETQHD)).

Answer (score 4):

The `static` keyword is the key! You need to declare the method as static:

```
class Hello_Misc {

   static public function fix_protocol($p1, $p2) {
      // code
   }

}
```

However, it you do so (and you should), you must make sure you're not using object context (i.e. `$this`) in this method. If you do, you will have to review your design a little.

Comment: ok now works :). but why it works in the oldest version of PHP 5 ?

Comment: You probably just have your `error_reporting` setting set to ignore `E_STRICT` errors. I do not encourage you to disable it though, because there warnings intend to make your code *acceptable* according to general programming standards and guidelines. e.g.: Calling a non-static method statically in C++, per example, will cause the compiler to fail and spit out an error.